# SVG rotate transform Matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg

I parsed a transform attribute from an element in an SVG file something like `rotate(45,30,50)` and I would like to transform it to matrix form.
I searched for it and all I could found is only for `rotate(a)` with no coordinates which looks like this `[cos(a) sin(a) -sin(a) cos(a) 0 0]`

can any one show me how to transform the `rotate(angle, x , y)` to matrix form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier way to get the transformation matrix of an SVG element.
Using the SVG element `getCTM()` method I can get the transformation matrix of the element, including rotation, translation and everything else.

Answer (score 8):

Rotation matrices can only describe rotations about (0, 0), so you'll have to use a translation.

**EDIT** See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raffaele181188/Cfdcn/). It draws a rectangle defined with an offset, width and height, rotated around a pivot point. The interesting part are the last 10 lines or so, where the value for `offsetX` and `offsetY` are computed. Once you have these, you can build your translation and your rotation matrices. Then, just multiply the translation by the rotation, and you'll get your final result. Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't offer any matrix functionality, so if you don't provide your code this is all I can do

**HOW A TRANSLATION MATRIX IS MADE**

```
1   0   offsetX
0   1   offsetY
0   0      1
```

**HOW A ROTATION MATRIX IS MADE**

```
cos   -sin    0
sin    cos    0
 0      0     1
```

[image: preview]

Comment: adding a translation will move the element, and this is not what I want.
What the point is for, is that it makes the rotation happens around it, rather than around (0,0)
the element is already in place, but needs rotation around a certain point

Comment: I wonder if he means that the net effect is te same - by rotating about the center and then offsetting, you can achieve the same thing?

Comment: the net effect is not the same.
All I want is to simply get the transformation matrix, so that I can apply it to some point on the shape, to get its place after rotation
if I offset the shape (translate it) I get the point in a different place.
I want the point in the same place but rotated around another point

Comment: As much as your solution seems to work, but it is to complicated for me to comprehend 
I simply need a function that takes a point and a rotation around a point, return the new location of the point
or a matrix representation of that solution

Comment: @zeacuss actually the only *complicated* part of my code are the last 10 lines, where I show how to compute the coordinates of `O'`, which is `O(0, 0)` rotated about the Pivot point `P(x, x)`. You can easily adapt my code to your needs simply by considering a new coordinate space where the arbitrary point `A(xA, yA)` becomes `(0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

To get svg transform matrix from  a rotation with pivot point,

check this question answer

[how to calculate svg transform matrix from rotation with pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660796/how-to-calculate-svg-transform-matrix-from-rotation-with-pivot-point)