# How to make a Clock Object from Scratch (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to make a clock object with out using the get methods i.e gethour, getminute, getsecond from java script and idea how to do so?

If i create an object with variables Hour, Minute and Second how do I get them to update them selves problematically.

I just want to create a clock to set time and display time.

```
// JavaScript Document
 function updateTime() { 

    // get all parts of the current time
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    if(hours < 10){
        hours = " " + hours
        }
    if(minutes < 10){
        minutes = "0" + minutes
        }
    if(seconds < 10){
        seconds = "0" + seconds
        } 

    // splice them together into a character string named "currentTime"
    var currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;    

    // get the clock div 
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clock');

    // write the currentTime string to the clock div
    myClock.innerHTML = currentTime;
    setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000)
}

function clock(){
    var time = new Date()
    var hr = time.getHours()
    var min = time.getMinutes()
    var sec = time.getSeconds()
    var ampm = " PM "
    if (hr < 12){
    ampm = " AM "
        }
    if (hr > 12){
    hr -= 12
        }
    if (hr < 10){
    hr = " " + hr
        }
    if (min < 10){
    min = "0" + min
        }
    if (sec < 10){
    sec = "0" + sec
        }

     // splice them together into a character string named "currentTime"
    var currentTime = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ampm;    

    // get the clock div 
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clock12');

    // write the currentTime string to the clock div
    myClock.innerHTML = currentTime;
    setTimeout("clock()", 1000)
}

function setClock(){
    var time = new Date()
    var hr = time.getHours()
    var min = time.getMinutes()
    var sec = time.getSeconds()
    var ampm = " PM "
    if (hr < 12){
    ampm = " AM "
        }
    if (hr > 12){
    hr -= 12
        }
    if (hr < 10){
    hr = " " + hr
        }
    if (min < 10){
    min = "0" + min
        }
    if (sec < 10){
    sec = "0" + sec
        }

     // splice them together into a character string named "currentTime"
    var currentTime = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ampm;    

    // get the clock div 
    var myClock = document.getElementById('setClock');

    // write the currentTime string to the clock div
    myClock.innerHTML = currentTime;
    setTimeout("setClock()", 1000)

}
```

Comment: my first step would be trying. like literally anything at all.

Comment: what "get methods"??

Comment: Your phrasing (`java script`, `get methods`) suggest you have not read any introductory material on Javascript. Start there.

Comment: okay sorry for the bad question i have edited it

Comment: I think you could find some tips there: [How to implement *object* for improve my clock sample javascript program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13208395/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get your clock to show "real" time without using the Date object. But if you just want to make an arbitrary clock for a game or something that is relative, you could do something like this:

```
var clock = {
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0
}

function updateTime(part, max) {
  return function(){
    clock[part]++
    if (clock[part] > max) clock[part] = 0
  }
}

setInterval(updateTime('hours', 24), 60*60*1000)
setInterval(updateTime('minutes', 60), 60*1000)
setInterval(updateTime('seconds', 24), 1000)
```

Comment: is there any way that you know of to update the time. lets say that i want to set the time and run the clock in real time