# how to calculate svg transform matrix from rotation with pivot point

Tags: matrix, svg, svg-animate

If there is a svg rotation( a deg) with default pivot point(0,0), then I can calculate the rotation transform matrix as

```
 _                    _
| cos a   -sin a   0   |
| sin a    cos a   0   |
|   0       0      1   |
 -                    -
```

But if pivot point is not (0,0), Lets say (px,py) then how do I calculate the rotation transform matrix?

Comment: I have answered my question, if you have any different ans please post your ans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the ans,

Lets the pivot point is **(px ,py)** and rotation is **a degree**
 then net transform matrix will be

```
                   _          _        _                      _    
                  |   1  0  px |      |   cos a    -sin a   0  |   
    net_matrix =  |   0  1  py |  X   |   sin a     cos a   0  |   
                  |   0  0  1  |      |     0         0     1  |   
                   -          -        -                      -    

                                               _             _
                                              |   1   0   -px |
    rotate_transform_matrix =  net_matrix  X  |   0   1   -py |
                                              |   0   0     1 |
                                               -             -
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to apply the rotation transform on an svg element:

```
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(-30 50 50)');
rect.getCTM();
```

to get The TransformMatrix.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiplying out (and tidying up the result to use the same variable names as the W3C) in case anyone else reading this wants something explicit.

```
rotate(a, cx, cy)
```

is equivalent to

```
matrix(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a), cx(1 - cos(a)) + cy(sin(a)), cy(1 - cos(a)) - cx(sin(a)))
```

Using mathematical notation assuming `rotate` and `matrix` are functions.

Comment: It looks like the last two matrix elements have the wrong sign, it should be `cx(1 - cos(a)) + cy(sin(a)), -cx(sin(a)) + cy(1 - cos(a))`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested in Swarnendu Paul `rotate_transform_matrix` above, one would get:

```
 _                                               _
| cos a   -sin a   px * (1 - cos a) + py * sin a  |
| sin a    cos a   py * (1 - cos a) - px * sin a  |
|   0        0                  1                 |
 ¯                                               ¯
```

I used it for SVG matrix transforms.