# How can I use an SVG element’s transformation matrix to calculate destination coordinates?

Tags: svg, dom, geometry, transformation, transformation-matrix

I suspect there is some way to use an element’s transformation matrix to calculate its coordinates after being transformed, but I don’t know how to do so.

An example diagram explains this best:

---

[image: A circle with points A, B, and a rotation center. A is the reference/starting point. B is like point A, but with a rotation applied around the rotation center. (All of the above is in a containing SVG, which is much larger in all directions. No assumptions can be made that the circle’s left bounding box matches the root SVG’s bounding box.) A: I know the distance from the rotation center, as well as the exact x and y coordinates. B: I can get a transformation matrix via B.getCTM(), but its x and y coordinates remain identical to those of A. Using the transformation matrix from B, I need to determine the x and y coordinates after transformation. In other words, I need the ability to create an element that appears in the same spot as B, but with no transformations applied.]

---

I’m afraid I didn’t take the math route into programming. I can sort-of follow the surface-level details of what a transformation matrix is doing, but my understanding is sort of like being able to read music one note at a time, and only very slowly; I don’t really understand the tune at a higher level, so I don’t really understand the sound of a complete musical phrase—let alone the melody.

Similarly, I don’t understand how transformation matrices work.  I have tried searching for explanations to grok transformation matrices, but everything I find is loaded with *more* math jargon I don’t understand.  I just know that they work sort of like a function, and that they are incredibly flexible tools, but that’s it.

Of all the methods available to `SVGMatrix` (supposedly deprecated in favor of `DOMMatrix`, but Firefox Dev. ed. is still using `SVGMatrix`), I have no idea whether `.inverse()` or `.multiply()` is what I want, and no idea how to coax a simple set of `x` and `y` coordinates out of that matrix.

**Note:**

- I am not interested in translating screen-to-SVG coordinates here.
- I am only concerned with SVG (user-space) coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple trigonometric transformation:

```
const rotatePoint = (point, center, rotateAngle) => {
  const dx = point.x - center.x;
  const dy = point.y - center.y;
  const distance = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  const currentAngle = Math.atan(dy / dx);
  const nextAngle = currentAngle - rotateAngle;
  const nextDX = distance * Math.cos(nextAngle);
  const nextDY = distance * Math.sin(nextAngle);
  return {x: center.x + nextDX, y: center.y + nextDY};
};
```

The snippet displays rotation of a blue point around the red one (30 / 90 / 123 degrees counter-clockwise)

```js
const rotatePoint = (point, center, angle) => {
    const dx = point.x - center.x;
  const dy = point.y - center.y;
  const distance = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  const current = Math.atan(dy / dx);
  const next = current - angle;
  const nextDX = distance * Math.cos(next);
  const nextDY = distance * Math.sin(next);
  return {x: center.x + nextDX, y: center.y + nextDY};
};

const center = {x: 150, y: 150};
const start = {x: 200, y: 30};
const svg = d3.select('svg');

svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', center.x)
  .attr('cy', center.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'red');
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', start.x)
  .attr('cy', start.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'blue');  

// Rotate 30 deg
const p30 = rotatePoint(start, center, Math.PI * 30 / 180); 
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', p30.x)
  .attr('cy', p30.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'green');  
// Rotate 90 deg
const p90 = rotatePoint(start, center, Math.PI * 90 / 180); 
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', p90.x)
  .attr('cy', p90.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'orange');
// Rotate 123 deg
const p123 = rotatePoint(start, center, Math.PI * 123 / 180); 
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', p123.x)
  .attr('cy', p123.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="250" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: This is good.  Thank you!  The only reason I can’t mark this an answer is: I figured that I could “Pythagoras” my way out of this, but I would prefer a solution that makes use of existing  `SVGMatrix` or `DOMMatrix` APIs.  I will nevertheless give this a shot as a temporary workaround.  Thank you.  

Comment: @Zearin maybe you can find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660796/how-to-calculate-svg-transform-matrix-from-rotation-with-pivot-point, but I'm not sure using matrices is simpler than a functional calculation, especially when it comes to the performance issues.

Comment: Your approach is definitely the simplest solution!  And since my original comment above, I’ve tried it, and it works quite well.  

The only reason I’m asking for a matrix-related solution is so that I will have something I can (theoretically) use on *any* transformed SVG element, and calculate the destination point(s) if I need to.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I wasn’t able to find the solution I wanted, so I’ve stuck with yours.  I’ll mark my question answered accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an SVG Circle,

You can calculate any SVG point on the circle with  the standard `getPointAtLength` and `getTotalLength` functions.

Just be aware where the circle ***starts***  drawing (green spot)

**pathLength converted to degrees:**

[image]

```html
<style>
  svg{ height:300px }
  text {
    font-size: 3px;
    fill: white;
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
  }
</style>
<svg id="SVG" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="pink"></circle>
  <circle id="CIRCLE" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%" 
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="2"></circle>
  <circle cx="90%" cy="50%" r="5%" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
<script>
  let circle_length = CIRCLE.getTotalLength();
  for (let degree = 0; degree < 360; degree += 45) {
    let { x , y } = CIRCLE.getPointAtLength(  degree * ( circle_length / 360 )  );
    let group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    group.innerHTML = `<circle cx="${x}" cy="${y}" r="3%" fill="blue"/>` +
                      `<text x="${x}" y="${y}">${degree}</text>`;
    SVG.append(group)
  }
</script>
```