# find points on svg arc command

Tags: typescript, svg

I'am trying to find points on arc defined in svg path.
I found this article about the problematic https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html, but i still have problems to implement it.

This is jsfiddle implementation that i have so far

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cb4e85L6/
```

arc is last command that i did not implement collider for to my small project

```
https://richardk123.github.io/physical-svg-examples/
```

Comment: Call [getPointAtLength](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength)

Comment: thnaks! that should solve it!

Comment: One more thing. Is there any way how can i find the length where the arc starts and end?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932094/how-can-i-use-an-svg-element-s-transformation-matrix-to-calculate-destination-co/66934247#66934247